# How to use Orbbec Astra sensor/camera on ROS to view pointcloud?

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library, 3dcamera, orbbec

I have installed ROS indigo, openni2, and plugged Orbbec Astra sensor in.
When I try to execute:

```
roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch
```

I get the warning that no device is connected:

```
No matching device found.... waiting for devices.
Reason: std::string openni2_wrapper::OpenNI2Driver::resolveDeviceURI(const string&)
@ /tmp/buildd/ros-indigo-openni2-camera-0.2.3-0trusty-20150327-
0611/src/openni2_driver.cpp @ 623 :
    Invalid device number 1, there are 0 devices connected.
```

How to view simple pointcloud in rviz using Orbbec Astra camera?

Answer (score 0):

Install these two packages: [ros_astra_camera](https://github.com/orbbec/ros_astra_camera) and [ros_astra_launch](https://github.com/orbbec/ros_astra_launch)

Follow instruction from the `ros_astra_camera` README.